# How can I access and update an AWS DynamoDB table in the cloud using Javascript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, cloud

I am working with AWS and need to understand how I can access and write to a table that is stored in the cloud. I know this has something to do with the Amazon Resource Name (ARN), but I'm not so sure of what to do. I am working with DynamoDB tables!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the right settings set up (region, profile):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html

After that use the sdk:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html